# Hide glibc output and segfault (system call)

Tags: perl, bash

I'm coding a shell like bash for a student project.
I need to make a `perl` *auto tester of line commands*.

```
my $cmd = "(echo \"foo\" | ./shell >& /dev/null)";
system($cmd);
if ($? == 35584) {
    print "SIGSEGV";
}
elsif ($? == 34304) {
    print "GLIB C";
}
else {
    print "GOOD";
}
```

I want to be able to hide the output on `segfault` or `glibc`.

@Marc B
Okay, but my shell read on output 0, so i must have "echo" :s

@drquicksilver
*** glibc detected**  ./shell: free(): invalid pointer: 0x0000000000608291 **
OR
Segmentation fault

Comment: remove the print statements?

Comment: Which output is displayed? What exactly do you want to hide?

Answer (score 1):

First of all, `system` executes `sh`, but you're using `csh` syntax.

```
my $cmd = "(echo \"foo\" | ./shell >& /dev/null)";
```

should be

```
my $cmd = "(echo \"foo\" | ./shell >/dev/null 2>&1)";
```

But executing shell can only interfere with your test. So let's avoid the shell entirely.

```
use Config   qw( %Config );
use IPC::Run qw( run );

sub sig_name {
   my ($sig_num) = @_;
   my %sig_names;
   @sig_names{ reverse split ' ', $Config{sig_num} } =
      reverse split ' ', $Config{sig_name};
   return $sig_names{$sig_num}
      ? "SIG$sig_names{$sig_num} (".($sig_num).")"
      : $sig_num;
}

run [ './shell' ], \"foo\n", '>','/dev/null', '2>&1';

if (my $sig_num = $? & 0x7F) {
   print "Killed by signal ".sig_name($sig_num)."\n";
} elsif (my $exit_code = $? >> 8) {
   print "Exited with error code $exit_code\n";
} else {
   print "GOOD\n";
}
```

What you call "GLIB C" is actually SIGABRT.

Comment: Great its works :D

I just have to do before:

sudo su

perl -MCPAN -e shell

install IPC::Run

Comment: But *** glibc detected *** ./42sh: free(): invalid pointer: 0x00000000006082b1 *** displayed again :s

Comment: Maybe it writes it directly to the terminal. IPC::Run does allow you to create pseudo TTYs easily.